# Why I can not change root to normal user in root script with shell?

Tags: shell

In my project, I have a shell delDATA.sh script.

In delDATA.sh script, I want to delete some files with rm command.

Due to rm command is prohibited of root in my company, so I want to change root to normal user zhangsan in script.

The core code of it like:

```
   if [ -d /home/recyclebin/$HName ]
   then
      #Due to rm is prohibited of root in my company, so it must change to normal user to execute rm
      su - zhangsan << EOF
      whoami;
      pwd;
      echo "rm -rf /tmp/"$FName;
      exit;
      EOF
      pwd
      whoami
      echo del
   fi
```

But unlucky, I got the error:

```
warning: here-document at line 24 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have tested in another independent test script, the content is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
su - zhangsan <<EOF
whoami;
pwd;
exit;
EOF
pwd
whoami
```

It works OK!!. So it should be changed user in first line?

It seems nothing wrong in delDATA.sh, Who can help me ?

Comment: Remove the spaces before the ending `EOF`.

Comment: OK!! wow, it works  OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 << EOF
```

Bash is space aware. Your here-document ends with a line that is exactly `EOF`. No spaces in front of it. The following code is invalid:

```
cat <<EOF
blabla
             EOF
```

There are spaces in front of EOF. You could do this:

```
cat << "       EOF"
blabla
       EOF
```

Ie. specify the spaces in front of EOF and end it with such line. The line is matched *exact*, tabs and spaces are not special. You script fixed would probably look like this:

```
   if [ -d /home/recyclebin/$HName ]
   then
      #Due to rm is prohibited of root in my company, so it must change to normal user to execute rm
      su - zhangsan << EOF
      whoami;
      pwd;
      echo "rm -rf /tmp/"$FName;
      exit;
EOF
      pwd
      whoami
      echo del
   fi
```

Bash doesn't find the `EOF` line you specified to end the here-document. So it tells you, that it read the whole file and the here-document didn't end. `here-document at line 24 delimited by end-of-file`.